# Is this sentence 'I'm gonna have to work on what else can she call me' correct?

Tags: word-order

1)I'm gonna have to work on what else can she call me.

2)You then wanna formulate an action plan. What steps can you take to start to address your worry

I watched a interview with Hillary on Ellen Show.

Hillary was talking about her granddaughter.
Ellen asked what she called Hillary

Hillary said on the show :

> She’s got a couple of words. I’m waiting to see what she wants to call
>   me. If I like it, I’ll say “yeah that’s a good one”. If I don’t, then
>   I’m gonna have to work on what else can she call me.

I thought that the last sentence was supposed to be like *I'm gonna have to work on what else she can call me**. Because 'what else she can call me' is not a question.
So, I thought she said it grammatically wrong.

BUT!!

I encountered another sentence *You then wanna formulate an action plan. What steps can you take to start to address your worry*, which is on You Tube.

I don't understand why they both said it in this order.

Comment: I think both of those sentences are wrong. You are correct in thinking that "she can" is the right order. Switching does make it a question.

Comment: If you are doing an interview on live TV, it is likely you make some mistakes. Obviously, the first one "what else can she call me" is a mistake. The second sentence "What steps can you take..." seems to be a question and a question mark should be placed.

Comment: Your question received three close-votes within 20 minutes after it was posted. If you are a speaker of other languages learning English, consider visiting our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Your question could be better received there.

Comment: I think this is a common style of informal speaking in southern dialects.

Comment: The task at hand is to analyze "what else can she call me".  Unconventional but valid syntax.